# How to disable custom layouts in magento based on a custom module state?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, mage

I have created a file called "myblock.phtml" in `frontend\default\default\layout\mytemplate` .It simply displays a "check " button which in turns calls a custom module's controller url.The question is,I want to stop displaying that button(i.e;the myblock.html template )
whenever that custom module is disabled since it doesnt make sense without the enabling the module.Any way to tweak within the module's config.xml??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//This is the code in my module's block "Checkbox.php" .Just might be useful for others..

```
<?php
class Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Checkbox extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

    //echos a text based on module state
    protected function checkstate() {

        $modules = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('modules')->children();
        $modulesArray = (array)$modules;

                             //my module name
        if($modulesArray['Mypackage_Myextension']->is('active')) {
            echo "Mypackage_Myextension is active.";
        } 
        else {
            echo "Mypackage_Myextension is not active.";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Thus,when i disable the module (System->Advanced->Disable Module),the block contents is not shown.

Comment: this is a bit overkill and you can just ask for your extension active state from config instead looping over all loaded extensions. And if your extension uses blocks then this condition is rather pointless as all block output is disabled anyway if the extension is disabled from admin page

Answer (score 0):

All templates should go through a block and in block you can make additional checks or let the default magento feature disable block output when your extension is disabled from administration page

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Anton's answer, create a custom block class that does something like this:

```
class Mypackage_Myextension_Block_Checkbox extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

    protected function _toHtml() {
        if(!$this->checkIfModuleIsEnabled()) {
            return "";
        }
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Think about using `Mage::helper('core')->isModuleOutputEnabled($moduleName)` in there somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely a good suggestion. Personally, I've never trusted Magento's output-disabling powers, but others may not see it the same way I do.

Comment: Thanks!! for the sample code.I made my module truly modular.Previously i invoked the template block directly ,but now i passed it to my module's block and made it to display the template.For unknown reasons,i cant post my Block code inside this comment box(getting scrambled)...